# How to make numpy.cumsum start after the first value

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I have:

```
import numpy as np

position = np.array([4, 4.34, 4.69, 5.02, 5.3, 5.7, ..., 4])
x = (B/position**2)*dt

A = np.cumsum(x)
assert A[0] == 0  # I want this to be true.
```

Where `B` and `dt` are scalar constants. This is for a numerical integration problem with initial condition of `A[0] = 0`. Is there a way to set `A[0] = 0` and then do a `cumsum` for everything else?

Comment: Could you use a short example with e.g. `position = [1, 2, 3, 4]` to clarify what you mean (what you would like), because it sounds to me like you don't fully understand the problem at hand yourself.

Comment: This won't work with `position` as `list` anyway, it has to be a `np.array`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly your problem is, but here are some things you can do to have `A[0] = 0`.

You can create A to be longer by one index to have the zero as the first entry:

```
# initialize example data
import numpy as np
B = 1
dt = 1
position =  np.array([4, 4.34, 4.69, 5.02, 5.3, 5.7])

# do calculation
A = np.zeros(len(position) + 1)
A[1:] = np.cumsum((B/position**2)*dt)
```

Result:

```
A = [ 0.          0.0625      0.11559096  0.16105356  0.20073547  0.23633533 0.26711403]
len(A) == len(position) + 1
```

Alternatively, you can manipulate the calculation to substract the first entry of the result:

```
# initialize example data
import numpy as np
B = 1
dt = 1
position =  np.array([4, 4.34, 4.69, 5.02, 5.3, 5.7])

# do calculation
A = np.cumsum((B/position**2)*dt)
A = A - A[0]
```

Result:

```
[ 0.          0.05309096  0.09855356  0.13823547  0.17383533  0.20461403]
len(A) == len(position)
```

As you see, the results have different lengths. Is one of them what you expect?

Answer (score 5):

I totally understand your pain, I wonder why Numpy doesn't allow this with `np.cumsum`. Anyway, though I'm really late and there's already another good answer, I prefer this one a bit more:

```py
np.cumsum(np.pad(array, (1, 0), "constant"))
```

where `array` in your case is `(B/position**2)*dt`. You can change the order of `np.pad` and `np.cumsum` as well. I'm just adding a zero to the start of the array and calling `np.cumsum`.

Answer (score 4):

### 1D cumsum

A wrapper around [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) that sets first element to `0`:

```
def cumsum(pmf):
    cdf = np.empty(len(pmf) + 1, dtype=pmf.dtype)
    cdf[0] = 0
    np.cumsum(pmf, out=cdf[1:])
    return cdf
```

Example usage:

```
>>> np.arange(1, 11)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

>>> cumsum(np.arange(1, 11))
array([ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55])
```

---

### N-D cumsum

A wrapper around [`np.cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) that sets first element to `0`, and works with N-D arrays:

```
def cumsum(pmf, axis=None, dtype=None):
    if axis is None:
        pmf = pmf.reshape(-1)
        axis = 0

    if dtype is None:
        dtype = pmf.dtype

    idx = [slice(None)] * pmf.ndim

    # Create array with extra element along cumsummed axis.
    shape = list(pmf.shape)
    shape[axis] += 1
    cdf = np.empty(shape, dtype)

    # Set first element to 0.
    idx[axis] = 0
    cdf[tuple(idx)] = 0

    # Perform cumsum on remaining elements.
    idx[axis] = slice(1, None)
    np.cumsum(pmf, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=cdf[tuple(idx)])

    return cdf
```

Example usage:

```
>>> np.arange(1, 11).reshape(2, 5)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])

>>> cumsum(np.arange(1, 11).reshape(2, 5), axis=-1)
array([[ 0,  1,  3,  6, 10, 15],
       [ 0,  6, 13, 21, 30, 40]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to simply add a `0` to the list on which you are performing the cumsum:

```py
import numpy as np

position = np.array([4, 4.34, 4.69, 5.02, 5.3, 5.7, ..., 4])
x = (B/position**2)*dt

# A = np.cumsum([0] + x) # This works only if x is a list
A = np.concatenate([[0], np.cumsum(x)]) # Both with lists and np arrays
```

This works both if `x` is a `list` or a `np.ndarray`.

Comment: This works if `x` is a `list` but not if it is an `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Ok, just checked up and you are right, it does not raise an error but it does not add the leading 0. This is probably due to the fact the in numpy the plus sign is used for the sum ufunc instead of the concatenation as in lists. A solution would be to use `np oncatenate`: `np.concatenate([[0],np.cumsum(x)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use roll (shift right by 1) and then set the first entry to zero.